# Can't execute 'onclick' using 'fire_event'

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a `div` menu which is hidden. `Div` includes a `span` with `onclick`:

```
onclick="parent.ClickMenuItem(this, '', 'http://some_link', 0); parent.wndPopupbtnMenu.hide();
```

When I try to execute it via `fire_event` nothing happens. But step becomes to passed.

```
page.spnMngUsers_element.fire_event :onclick
```

Page object of `spnMngUsers`:

```
in_iframe(:id => 'PortalSubmenuFrame') do |frame|
  span(:spnMngUsers, :xpath => "//span[text()='Users']", :frame => frame)
end
```

P.S.: Application based on `iframe`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use fire_event, you don't give status, but action.

```
page.spnMngUsers_element.fire_event('click')
```

Comment: Nope, does't work. Still step becomes to pass but `onlick` wasn't executed. And `:onclick` works for open hidden submenu.